# Get the current directory status information?

Tags: libgit2

**int git_status_list_new**(git_status_list **out, git_repository *repo, const git_status_options *opts);
// it is get the repository status,but I care only about files located in a single directory. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I want to Commit , than, I can gets the status of the current directory.

Comment: ye, it is the same question, think you very much！